# Missing CultureInfo on Server 2008 R2 x64

Tags: c#, .net, cultureinfo

We have a Server 2008 R2 x64 machine that is throwing for culture "en-ID", while my dev machine (Windows 7 x64) works fine.

`new CultureInfo("en-id", false);`

Error:
Culture name 'en-id' is not supported.
Parameter name: name

Do I need language packs or something? I haven't been able to find much information about how .NET populates the CultureInfo stuff.

Cheers,
Ty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no [`en-id`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533052%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The valid `en` codes are:

```
en          English
en-us   English (United States)     
en-gb   English (United Kingdom)
en-au   English (Australia)     
en-ca   English (Canada)
en-nz   English (New Zealand)   
en-ie   English (Ireland)
en-za   English (South Africa)  
en-jm   English (Jamaica)
en          English (Caribbean)     
en-bz   English (Belize)
en-tt   English (Trinidad)
```

Comment: Then why does it work on my dev machine? According to: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964664 it is a valid LCID.

Comment: @Ty - An LCID is a number, not an IETF name.  Why don't you tell us which one in that list you want?

Comment: Could be that Windows 7 is parsing the `en-id` as `en` as succeed, and Server 2008 R2 is consider it as error. What `CultureInfo.LCID` do you get on Win 7 when setting it to `"en-id"` ?

Comment: I'm beginning to suspect I somehow got a custom culture installed. LCID for en-id on my dev machine is 1033 (en-US). Even weirder is production somehow got that culture too. :|